# Is there an easy way to convert an XML structure into a tree to store in a database?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, tree

Specifically, I want to convert the XML structure into this format for the database so that I can use modified preorder tree traversal:

[image: database structure]
<sub>(source: [sitepointstatic.com](http://sitepointstatic.com/graphics/table02.gif))</sub>

My XML structure looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<products>
    <node>
      <name>Top Membership</name>
      <node>
        <name>Middle Membership</name>
        <node>
          <name>Bottom Membership</name>
          <node>
            <name>Some content</name>
            <node>
              <name>Specific content</name>
            </node>
          </node>
        </node>
      </node>
    </node>
```

I've made a PHP script to traverse the XML structure and dump me out the names, I'm just having trouble working out the left and right values. I think I probably have to change my traversal logic so that it's followed down to a single leaf each time, then goes back up and starts again, rather than bottoming each entire branch each time. If I could do this then I think it would be easier to calculate left and right.

My PHP script so far:

```
<?php

$node = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents('products.xml'));

echo '<pre>';

function getRowData($node, $depth)
{  
  //Not a leaf
  if(isset($node->node))
  {
    echo $node->name."\t\t\t($depth) parent, children: ".count($node->children())."\n";

    foreach($node->node as $n)
      getRowData($n, $depth + 1);
  }
  else //It's a leaf
    echo $node->name."\t\t\t($depth) leaf\n";


}

getRowData($node->node, 1);

echo '</pre>';

?>
```

I'm using this SitePoint article for reference http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/

**Edit:**

Revised PHP script which is closer to a solution (and outputs in a better format with more (possibly relevant) numbers):

```
<?php

$node = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents('products.xml'));

echo '<table border="1">';
  echo '
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Depth</th>
      <th>Child num</th>
      <th>Children</th>
      <th>Ancestors</th>
      <th>Total siblings</th>
      <th>"Left"</th>
      <th>Parent "Left"</th>
    </tr>';

function getRowData($node, $depth = 1, $child_num = 1, $prior_nodes = 0, $sibling_total = 0, $parent_left = 0)
{  

    echo '<tr>';
  echo '
          <td>'.$node->name."</td>
          <td>$depth</td>
          <td>$child_num</td>
          <td>".(count($node->children()) - 1)."</td>
          <td>$prior_nodes</td>
          <td>$sibling_total</td>";

  $left = $parent_left + ($child_num == 1 ? 1 : ($child_num * 2) - 1);


          echo "<td>$left</td>";
          echo "<td>$parent_left</td>";
  echo '</tr>';
  $child_num = 1;

  foreach($node->node as $n)
  {
    getRowData(
            $n, 
            $depth + 1, 
            $child_num++, 
            $prior_nodes + (count($node->children()) - 1), 
            (count($node->children()) - 1),
            $left
    );
  }
}

getRowData($node->node);

echo '</table>';

?>
```

Comment: Your XML has nothing to do with your shown table.  Please ensure that your data matches.  I'm at a total loss how/what that table data means or where it's coming from.

Comment: It's just a representation of the format which I'm trying to achieve, the data is irrelevant. The SitePoint article has more details of that particular example.

My example XML in that format is too trivial to bother specifying in the intended output because every node only has 1 or 0 children (I should probably have made up a better example).

Comment: the row data shoul be printed after the recursive calss, since you do not know the right index before they have finished

Comment: @newtover I understand what you're saying but I don't think the right index is going to be a problem once the left index is solved. If I'm not mistaken I can calculate the right index using: right = left + 1 + (sum of all children * 2)

Comment: It depends on how balanced your tree is. By the way, be sure to treat node and name elements differently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general approach here is to create an adjacency list (a tree), then
traverse the tree assigning `lft` on your way down and `rgt` on your way up.

Assuming this xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<products>
<node><name>Top Membership</name>
  <node><name>Middle Membership</name>
    <node><name>Bottom Membership 1</name></node>
    <node><name>Bottom Membership 2</name>
      <node><name>Some content</name>
        <node><name>Specific content</name></node>
      </node>
    </node>
  </node>
</node>
</products>
```

The following code should do what you need.

```php
$root = simplexml_load_string($xml);

function nested_set($parent, $rows=array(), $counter=1) {
    foreach ($parent->node as $node) {
        $row = array(
            'title'   => (string) $node->name,
            'parent' => (string) $parent->name,
            'lft'    => $counter++,
            'rgt'    => null,
        );
        list($rows, $counter) = nested_set($node, $rows, $counter);
        $row['rgt'] = $counter++;
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    return array($rows, $counter);
}

function print_rows($rows) {
    $sep = '+'.str_repeat('-', 22).'+'.str_repeat('-', 22).'+'.str_repeat('-', 5).'+'.str_repeat('-', 5).'+'."\n";
    echo $sep;
    echo vsprintf("| %-20s | %-20s | %3s | %3s |\n", array_keys($rows[0]));
    echo $sep;
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        echo vsprintf("| %-20s | %-20s | %3d | %3d |\n", array_values($row));
    }
    echo $sep;
}

list($rows, $counter) = nested_set($root);
// rows will be in reverse-traversal order
print_rows($rows);
```

Output will be:

```
+----------------------+----------------------+-----+-----+
| title                | parent               | lft | rgt |
+----------------------+----------------------+-----+-----+
| Bottom Membership 1  | Middle Membership    |   3 |   4 |
| Specific content     | Some content         |   7 |   8 |
| Some content         | Bottom Membership 2  |   6 |   9 |
| Bottom Membership 2  | Middle Membership    |   5 |  10 |
| Middle Membership    | Top Membership       |   2 |  11 |
| Top Membership       |                      |   1 |  12 |
+----------------------+----------------------+-----+-----+
```

For more information on nested sets, see Joe Celko's work:

- [Trees in SQL](http://www.ibase.ru/devinfo/DBMSTrees/sqltrees.html)
- The chapter on trees and hierarchies in [SQL for Smarties](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123820227) (I have the first edition--it's *very valuable*.)
- His book [Trees and Hierarchies in SQL for Smarties](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123877334)

Comment: This seems perfect. Just testing it now. I was getting rather close with my own script too, but it was getting very hacky.

Comment: Thanks, it works great. I will save my blushes and not bother posting what I had so far...! I hope people can find this in the future because it seems there's nothing readily available to show you how to do this elsewhere on the net.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the XQuery PHP extension for doing this: http://www.zorba-xquery.com/site2/html/php.html

Comment: Could you elaborate on how exactly that this extension would help with my problem? The documentation is very generic. I've got to here and cannot see how it would help: http://www.zorba-xquery.com/site2/doc/latest/zorba/xqdoc/xhtml/www.zorba-xquery.com_modules_xml.html